# Dump Curvature Information for 3d Models

Tags: 3d, mesh, point-cloud-library, meshlab

Is anyone aware of any utility to generate and dump Principal, Gaussian and Mean Curvatures for a 3D Model or a set of points?
I have reserched following tools -

- meshlab
- cloudcompare

They are able to compute the curvatures, but they do not have the option to dump it.

I need to get this information for my dataset which consists of like 200 models and would need to dump the curvature info for the same.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Meshlab can do it easily. When you apply a filter (such as curvature) the values are stored in a per-vertex field named quality. You can save to file choosing ply format and enabling the "quality" checkbox. Probably you want check the ascii checkbox too, to read the values without a ply parser.

See my answer to this question to a more elaborate example of storing curvature as quality values.

[meshlab: Does the topology of my mesh effect the curvature results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194552/meshlab-does-the-topology-of-my-mesh-effect-the-curvature-results/59266954#59266954)

Comment: I have previously seen your answer and did understand better about curvatures. However, your solution here is not feasible since I have hundreds of files for which i need to generate principal curvatures.

Comment: Yes, it is. Meshlab includes a program named meshlabserver which allows you to run on a batch of files without requiring interaction with the user.